# 'FacebookCore' does not specify a Swift version and none of the targets ('AppName') integrating it have the 'SWIFT_VERSION' attribute set

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

i am getting this error when i trying to install pod.

Error:-
```['FacebookCore' does not specify a Swift version and none of the targets ('AppName') integrating it have the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute set. Please contact the author or set the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute in at least one of the targets that integrate this pod.

- 'FacebookShare' does not specify a Swift version and none of the targets ('AppName') integrating it have the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute set. Please contact the author or set the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute in at least one of the targets that integrate this pod.]```

Here is my pod file detail:-

```
   use_frameworks!

  # Pods for AppName
  pod 'AppsFlyerFramework'
  pod 'FacebookShare'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
end

using xcode 11.3.1 and not using any swift class
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried to add Swift class in project and added "AppName-Bridging-Header.h". Then it's working fine.